# Парсирование XML

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Есть переменная $cit , в значение которой занесен xml-документ :

```
$cit = file_get_contents('https://api.musement.com/api/v3/cities');
$xml = simplexml_load_file($cit);
echo '<pre>' ;
echo $xml->entry->top->name ;
```

Что не так ?

Comment: а так `print_r($xml->entry->top)`?

Comment: Тоже самое , оно почему-то ругается на строку $xml = simplexml_load_file($cit);

Comment: Люди здесь не телепаты - пишите текст ошибок.

Comment: Может у вас вообще php-xml не установлен.

Comment: Вот такая ошибка : simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity

Comment: используйте `simplexml_load_string`

Comment: Пробовал,там такая вот ошибка : simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

Comment: `print($cit);` - проверьте что лежит в $cit.

Comment: такой вывод : [{"id":57,"uuid":"416f5475-3384-11ea-a8ce-06c1426e0cac","top":false,"name":"Amsterdam",".....}]

Comment: ну вот, не xml.

Comment: вот теперь ещё непонятнее стало , по ссылке находится xml-файл , но в переменную $cit заносится строка ,почему так ?

Comment: Сервер вправе выдавать все что хочет в зависимости от параметров передаваемых клиентом. `file_get_contents` - возвращает не файл(дескриптор), а содержимое файла.

Comment: А можно как-то именно файл вернуть ?

Comment: Можно подобрать параметры которые [передаются](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#example-2612) - нужно отправлять данные User-Agent к примеру. Но проще использовать json-парсер, вы же json получили.

Comment: Разве JSON.parse($cit) в php сработает ? там же нет такого метода

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php